# Como utilizar NoSql evitando sql-injection?

Tags: sql, mongodb

No relacional estou acostumado a criar parâmetros para cada campo que será atualizado que ajuda a evitar SQL Injection.

estava olhando por exemplo no (Node.js + o MongoDB). Você pode enviar solicitações facilmente com consultas de API. Um exemplo típico de uma solicitação do MongoDB seria algo assim:

```
customers.find({ name:{$gt: 'diego'} }, callback);
```

assim o invasor poderia enviar um objeto para a consulta em vez de uma string?

se sim, como podemos evitar essa validação?

Comment: se vc usa o `Express` há um package chamado "Express Sanitize" ou algo assim que valida os inputs.... faça validação manual também, há regex na internet para validar isso, basta copiar aplicar sobre os parâmetros

Comment: Garanta que o valor sempre seja String ou Number, de resto creio que seja improvável o usuário passar um valor como uma Function no $where, o ataque só aconteceria se fosse um erro por parte do desenvolvedor, por exemplo: `$where: function() { função que pode causar um ataque }`, mas não vejo como uma requisição por parte do usuário teria a "permissão" de escrever uma função como ele desejar, a não ser que você tenha inventado de usar algo como eval().... De qualquer forma não me parece correto chamar de SQL-Injection, talvez "NoSQL injection".

Comment: É realmente faz sentido, valeu :)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Em geral em meus projetos eu resolvo este problema fazendo a sanitização e validação da entrada em uma etapa anterior ao envio dos valores para o banco de dados. Desta forma os dados de entrada são todos "limpos" antes mesmo de serem processados pelo SGBD.

Em geral eu uso libs auxiliares que possuem este papel de validar e sanitizar os dados.

Um exemplo concreto de implementação (em javascript) é utilizar a lib `express-validator`

Um caso concreto de implementação, desejo que seja obrigatório um JSON em que ele obedeça algumas restrições de validação por exemplo:

- deve conter a chave `username` no body
- deve conter a chave `senha` no body
- o valor da chave `username` não pode ser vazio
- o valor da chave `senha` não pode ser vazio

Uma implementação concreta deste tipo de validação pode ser feita da seguinte forma:

```
const { body } = require('express-validator');

exports.validationBodyRules = [
    body('username', 'username é obrigatório').exists(),
    body('senha', 'senha é obrigatório').exists(),
    body('username', 'username é obrigatório').notEmpty(),
    body('senha', 'senha é obrigatório').notEmpty()
];
```

- deve conter a chave `temperatura_operacional` no body
- o valor da chave `temperatura_operacional` deve ser um inteiro entre -50 e 95 graus
- deve conter a chave `nome` no body
- o valor da chave `nome` deve ser alfanumérico (letras e números) e possuir um tamanho máximo de 19 caracteres.

Um caso concreto em que há uma validação com mais regras, seria o seguinte:

```
const { body } = require('express-validator');

exports.validationPostbody = [
    body('nome', 'nome é obrigatório').exists(),
    body('temperatura_operacional', 'temperatura_operacional é obrigatório').exists(),
    body('nome', 'nome é obrigatório').isAlphanumeric().isLength({ max: 19 }),
    body('temperatura_operacional', 'temperatura_operacional is required').isInt({ min: -50, max: 95 }),
];
```

Esta implementação considera que estas regras devem ser obedecidas para poderem ser uma requisição válida, em caso de não estar em conformidade então é retornado um status de erro (erros http da série 4xx) esta validação deve ocorrer em middlewares antes dessas requisições serem processadas pelo SGBD.

Você pode conhecer as validações disponíveis indo no site da [documentação da lib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-validator). Mas as validações disponíveis são apenas um wrapper das validações disponíveis na lib [validator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/validator).